# In The Last Jedi, how did Rey hurt Kylo Ren

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

There was a scene in TLJ that confuses me between Rey and Kylo Ren.

> One of the many times they had a connection from a distance, Rey "shot" Kylo with a blaster.  She appeared to hurt him when she shot, even though they were separated by a great distance and the blast shot a hole in her hut and never touched him.

How did this happen?  They were separated by a great distance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I do not believe that Rey actually injured Ren in this sequence, he simply flinched in a moment of 'phantom' pain as at this stage he was not completely aware of what was happening (as in that he may have thought that Rey was physically there as opposed to the 'force connection' induced by Snoke).

I cannot remember exactly where he thought he felt the 'phantom' injury on his body but as far as I can recall it appeared to be in the same spot that Chewbacca shot him in *Star Wars - The Force Awakens* with the bowcaster seconds after he murdered Han, which may have contributed to the illusion of pain.